# Law of non-contradiction violated

Tags: principle-of-non-contradiction

Can we consider these three examples as a violation of the law of non-contradiction?

- The photon (and also some other particles) is mathematically its own particle AND anti-particle
- The Moebius strip has the strip that is at the same time the external side and it's own opposite (internal side)
- The Klein bottle has the external surface that is at the same time its opposite (internal surface)

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) no; see [Why is a photon its own anti-photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189415/why-is-a-photon-its-own-anti-photon)

Comment: Same for the others; compare with "is zero odd or even?" Maybe neither, maybe both...

Comment: idt so, but thanks for the question, Vincent :-)

Comment: No. Coinciding with the "opposite" is only contradictory when the "opposite" is so defined as to entail a contradiction. In these examples, it is not. A particle with "opposite physical charges" may well be the same as the original if it has no charges, "external" side may be the same as "internal" side when the surface is one-sided, etc. That "opposites" are "usually" different in practice does not make the difference logically necessary.

Comment: Simpler: _Does a contradiction violate the law of non-contradiction_? Answer, depends on the use: yes, if it affects the logic of the proposition set (e.g. `this is a contradiction`), and no, if it is just an object in the set (`1. The contradiction is simple; 2. The contradiction exists`: this is fine logic about a contradiction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we consider these three examples as a violation of the law of non-contradiction?

No.

In formal logic, a contradiction is just A ∧ ¬A, where '∧' denotes the conjunction, and '¬' the negation.

The Law of Contradiction (LoC) just says that contradictions are just false. This may be expressed as follows:

> ¬(A ∧ ¬A)

The LoC is just the expression of the fact that given the semantic of the conjunction (∧) and of the negation (¬), the conjunction A ∧ ¬A can only be false.

Thus, the truth of the LoC does not depend on any matter of empirical fact outside the fact of our own semantic.

> The photon (and also some other particles) is mathematically its own particle AND anti-particle

The two sentences "The photon is its own particle" and "The photon is its own anti-particle" are not mutually contradictory.

They are not contradictory in particular if you assume the scientific definition of particle and anti-particle, which according to what you say make the two sentences "The photon is its own particle" and "The photon is its own anti-particle" both true, at the same time, and therefore not contradictory to each other.

> The Moebius strip has the strip that is at the same time the external side and it's own opposite (internal side)

Same explanation.

Now, keep in mind that if you had prefaced this sentence by some ad hoc definition to the effect that the internal side and the external side cannot be the same side, then by asserting both the sentence and this ad hoc definition, ***you would indeed contradict yourself***!

The same applies to the case of the photon.

> The Klein bottle has the external surface that is at the same time its opposite (internal surface)

Same.

Answer (score 0):

None of the examples violates the law of non-contradiction.

The trivial reason is that the law of non-contradition refers to the truth value of **propositions**. But the objects of your examples are not propositions.

The law of non-contradiction states: If A is a proposition, then

> not (A and non-A)

i.e. never both a statement A and its negation non-A are valid.

Simple example: A = “Now it rains in Manhattan”.

Your examples do not deal with propositions and their negation: The photon is a particle while the two other examples are mathematical concepts.

- Example 1: The mirror-particle of the photon is the photon itself.
- Example 2: There is not an internal and an external side of the
  Moebius strip. Distinguishing two global sides of a Moebius strip is
  a meaningless concept. Only locally one can distinguish two sides.
- Example 3: The [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle) is an analogous, but more complicated example than the Moebius strip.

**Added**: Corrected due to a comment.

Comment: Moebius strip is also 2-dimensional.

Comment: @Mikhail Katz Many thanks. I corrected the statement.

Comment: The Klein bottle can be immersed in 3-space but it cannot be embedded in 3-space.

Comment: You are right, but I want to avoid the technical terms immersion and embedding.

Comment: But the Klein bottle *is* "an object within 3-dimensional Euclidean space", contrary to what you claim.  Unlike the real projective plane, which isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I have been mistaken concerning the hole of penetration.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jo Wehler's answer and @Conifold's comment.

I would like though, to give an answer in a wider philosophical context, i.e. outside the somehow formalized framework of logic.

According to Parmenides, which was the first to conceive or identify the *principle of identity* which was later named as *law of non-contradiction* : A is by necessity A, A cannot be A and B at the same time.

> For Parmenides, the mark of what is known is that it is something that
> genuinely is (A), with no taint of what-is-not (B). That is why, for him, it
> not only is, but must be and cannot not-be. [link 4. Parmenides of Elea...](https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2011/entries/presocratics/#ParEle)

In this context, for example the strip (A=) is at the same time the external side and it's own opposite: it's a fact.

A violation would be if the strip (A) was at the same time equal to B, where B = (for example) the strip is only the external side; but it is not.